# Estimation: Repeating to decrease probability of failure

Tags: probability, computational-complexity, estimation

In a standard Bernoulli experiment with some constant probability of failure $p$ one can estimate the number of repetitions necessary to get at least one success to some other arbitrary desired probability of failure $\epsilon$. In other words, by repeating the experiment $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$, one can shrink the probability of failure to get at least one success from $p$ to $\epsilon$.

Now, consider a similar but different scenario. Say, I have a procedure to estimate some real number $a$ up to some additive error $\eta$ which has probability of failure $p<1/2$, i.e. in every round of an experiment, the probability of the estimate $a'$ to fall into the interval $[a-\eta, a+\eta]$ is $1-p$ but with probability $p$ my estimate $a'$ falls outside.

I want to prove that again $O(\log (1/\epsilon))$ repetitions of this procedure are enough to decrease the probability of failure to any arbitrary $\epsilon$. However, in comparison to the above, I do not know which of the rounds succeeded and which failed. Intuitively, I should take the mean or maybe the median of all the estimates $a'_i$ but how to prove that the scaling with $O(\log (1/\epsilon))$ works out?

Comment: Is it acceptable to cross post this at CS / CS.theory stack exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The median works**

Suppose that, after $n$ trials, the median of the $a_i'$ falls outside of the interval $[a-\eta,a+\eta]$. WLOG the median is greater than $a+\eta$. Since half of the $a_i'$ are greater than or equal to the median, at least half of these $n$ trials have been failures.

So an upper bound of the probability of the median falling outisde the interval is $F(n,\lceil\frac{n}2 \rceil,p)$, the probability of at least $\lceil\frac{n}2 \rceil$ failures after $n$ trials of a Bernoilli process with failure rate $p$.

In fact, if there is a half chance that the $a_i'$ are unifomly distributed in $[a-\eta,a+2\eta]$ and a half chance that the $a_i'$ are uniformly distributed in $[a-2\eta,a+\eta]$, then this bound is exact.

[The asymptotic behaviour of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds) $F(n,k,p)$  is given by Hoeffding's inequality:

$F(n,k,p)\le \exp\left( -2 \frac{(np-k)^2}{n} \right) \quad$         (1)

We want to prove that there exists a $c$ such that $F(n,\lceil\frac{n}2 \rceil,p)\le \epsilon$ whenever $n>c\log\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Using (1) we have that

$F(n,\lceil\frac{n}2 \rceil,p)\le \exp\left[ \frac{-2\left(c\log\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)(p-\frac{1}{2})\right)^2}{c\log\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\right]=\epsilon^{2c(p-\frac{1}{2})^2}$.

So $c=\frac{1}{2(p-\frac{1}{2})^2}$ will do.

**Why the $p<\frac{1}{2}$ condition is required.**

Suppose that $a'=a$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, $a'=b$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$,  and $b$ is outside the interval $[a-\eta,a+\eta]$.

Then the value of $a$ can be narrowed down to one of two numbers, but no matter how many times the experiment is repeated it is impossible to guess which of the two numbers is $a$ and which one is $b$ without being wrong half the time.

Comment: Yes, good point. But for any probability of failure $p<1/2$, one should be able to boost it to arbitrary precision, right? and thats what I am interested in.

Comment: @Marsl Yes, you are right about the p<1/2 case.

Comment: Great answer. So simple :) Now, I wonder whether something similar is possible for the mean. I mean, intuitively, the mean should also work but then again, you do not get  the implication of half of the trials falling outside the interval if the mean falls outside so I am not sure how to proceed? Do you happen to have thought about that?

Comment: If $a'=0$ with probability $p$ and $a'=a$ with probability $1-p$ then the mean converges to $a(1-p)$.